# blpop pretend death with redis3 using spring-data-redis

Tags: java, redis

application program is running without exception, jstack shown normal,IO loading、memory using both were right. blpop command is always blocking without consuming record.

```
RedisConnection connection = .... 
connection.bLPop(0, key);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: appliction has kept consuming data from redis successfully unitl now,  above problem occurred. after rebooting app,it works correctly.

Comment: List<byte[]> headerValues = connection.bLPop(0, stringSerializer.serialize(key));  couldn't consume data from redis,in order to increase message in redis list